# Missing required request parameters: [version]

Tags: aws-api-gateway

When I hit my aws api-gateway endpoint:

`https://a3hxca5y00.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<stage>/path`

I receive a 400 error with the message 'Missing required request parameters: [version]'.

If I add a function version like this, the call succeeds:

`https://a3hxca5y00.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<stage>/path:v2`

My understanding is that the default endpoint should execute the $LATEST API version, yet this is not happening. How can I fix this?

Comment: default is $latest unless you have changed the configuration to point to a specific version. Probably, more details like APIG pics would be helpful